# How to add a new div row by row on button click in php?

Tags: php, json, for-loop, input

I have a **html/php** code as shown below: 
The idea is to click on the PLUS (+) button and generate a new row with the HTML present in **newRow()** function. **HTML/PHP** code has 2 input boxes.

**html/php code:**

```
<?php
$output = array();     
$output['en_desc']=$_POST['en_desc'];
$output['code']=$_POST['code'];

$fp = fopen('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_committees.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
fclose($fp);

if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_committees.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_committees.json'));
}
?>

<?php if($data) { ?>
<form method="post" id="myform" style="text-align: left;">

    <!-- Add New Row Button START -->
    <div class="plus-minus-button" style="text-align:center;">    
         <button type="button" onclick="rowAdd()">+</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Add New Row Button END -->

    <div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;"> <!-- Big div START -->

    <!-- Code START -->  
    <?php if (empty($data->code)) { ?>
         <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">
          <?php } else {  ?>
        <?php  foreach ($data->code as $code){ ?>            <!-- Line A -->
          <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="<?php if($code) {echo $code;}?>">
         <?php }} ?>
    <!-- Code END -->

    <!-- EN Desc START -->  
    <?php if (empty($data->en_desc)) { ?>
         <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="">
          <?php } else {  ?>
        <?php  foreach ($data->en_desc as $en_desc){ ?>      <!-- Line B -->
          <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="<?php if($en_desc) {echo $en_desc;}?>">
         <?php }} ?>
    <!-- EN Desc END -->

    </div>  <!-- Big div END -->
</form>
<?php } else {
echo 'Cannot read JSON settings file';
}
?>
```

Here is the **JavaScript** which I am using in order to add a div in JavaScript.

```
 <script>       
        function rowAdd() {
          document.querySelector(".house-senate-committee:last-child").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', newRow());
        }

        function newRow() {
              return `<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
                    <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">   
                    <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="">
              </div>`;

         }  
</script>
```

**Problem Statement:**

At **Line A** and **Line B**, I am using ***for loop*** inside **div.house-senate-committee** so that can be the reason why its not showing in the way I want. I am wondering what changes I should make at **Line A/B (for loop)** so that I can get the **DOM in the way I want**.

The above javascript code shows content but its not **adding div element row by row like this**:

```
<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
    <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="ABC">
    <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="DEF">
</div>

<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
    <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="QWE">
     <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="RTY">
</div>
```

Its adding in the following way **(which is not I want)**:

```
<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;"> <!-- Big div START -->
    <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="ABC">
    <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="QWE">

    <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="DEF">
    <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="RTY">
</div>                                                                           <!-- Big div END -->
```

Comment: Maybe you should not add that row after the last child of `house-senate-committee`, but after the last `div` with that class? Additionally, how does the given JS code produce the lines containing `fr_desc` while this is not present in any other code?

Comment: @NicoHaase If you read my problem statement. I think, it has to do something with the for loop at **Line A** and **Line B** in the code above.

Comment: @NicoHaase If you read my problem statement. 

I think, it has to do something with the for loop at Line A and Line B in the code above. Line A and Line B have for loops whhich is calling all **input type ="text"** 
so thats the reason why I am getting all inputs type inside div which is not the way I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$data` is empty you just have to print a single div with empty inputs.
If `$data` has data you have to iterate through your data, print a div for each entry and fill the inputs with the corresponding values.

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
$output = array();     
$output['en_desc']=$_POST['en_desc'];
$output['code']=$_POST['code'];

$fp = fopen('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_committees.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
fclose($fp);

if(file_exists('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_committees.json')){
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_committees.json'));
}
?>

<?php if($data) { ?>
<form method="post" id="myform" style="text-align: left;">

    <!-- Add New Row Button START -->
    <div class="plus-minus-button" style="text-align:center;">    
         <button type="button" onclick="rowAdd()">+</button>
    </div>
    <!-- Add New Row Button END -->

<?php if(empty($data->code)){ ?>

    <div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;"> <!-- Big div START -->
         <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">
         <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="">
    </div>

<?php }else { ?>

<?php foreach($data->code as $key=>$value){ ?>


    <div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;"> <!-- Big div START -->

         <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="<?=$data->code[$key]?>">
         <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="<?=$data->en_desc[$key]?>">


    </div>  <!-- Big div END -->

    <?php 
        } 
      }
    ?>

</form>
<?php } else {
echo 'Cannot read JSON settings file';
}
?>
```

Comment: Inside **../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_committees.json**, I am having this **{"code": null,"en_desc": null}** at the moment. When there 
is something inside **../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_committees.json**, it looks like this **{"code": ["abc"],"en_desc":["hello world"]}**. 
When there are more contents, it looks like this **{"code": ["abc", "def"],"en_desc":["hello world", "I am good"]}**. It must
have answered your 1st question. Yes, all the JSON object arrays have the same number of indexes.

Comment: **Quick question:** Why are you using `!empty` for `$en_code` and `$en_desc` ? It will go inside `foreach loop` only if its `($data->code and $data->en_desc)` not null.

Comment: **In general**, **../feeds/ptp-ess_landing_committees.json** looks like this:

`{
 "ptp_status": null,
 "code": ["XYZ"],
 "en_desc": ["Hello World "],
 "fr_desc": ["Crazy World"],
 "toggle_status": null
}`

Comment: Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Hi George, I hope all is well. I have one more [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60532447/array-filter-doesnt-seems-to-work-for-words-having-apostrophe-and-dash). I am wondering if you can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * @param {String} HTML representing a single element
 * @return {Element}
 */
function htmlToElement(html) {
    var template = document.createElement('template');
    html = html.trim(); // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result
    template.innerHTML = html;
    return template.content.firstChild;
}

function rowAdd() {
    document.querySelector("#house-senate-committee-parent-div").appendChild(htmlToElement(newRow)));
}
```

note I am selecting the rows parent div (i.e. the div you use as a container to put the rows in)

^^That may not even be the issue I just don't like how the element was being added previously.

PHP wise it looks like instead of adding inputs wrapped with a div you are just adding input tags. You want to add the div with the input in it each time. It looks to definitely be a problem with your php for each loops. Add the divs with the inputs inside them in the loop not just the inputs

[image]

^See how you are adding all the input tags to one div instead of making a separate div every time in the loop?

Comment: I think it has to do something with the php code at Line A/Line B, not the javascript code I believe. Thoughts ?

Comment: taking a look at that now

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below code

```
<div class="plus-minus-button" style="text-align:center;">    
         <button type="button" id="addrow">+</button>
</div> 

<div id="main-div" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
</div>

<script>
     $(document).on('click','#addrow',function()
     {    
          $('#main-div').append('<div class="house-senate-committee" style="text-align:center; margin-top:15px;">
              <input type="text" name="code[]" style="margin-right:10px;" value="">   
              <input type="text" name="en_desc[]" value="">
          </div>');    
     });
</script>
```